# GridPanel CheckboxSelectionModel - Sum selected

Tags: javascript, c#, extjs

How can I sum a particular column of all selected rows? (Via javascript)

```
    <script>
        var sumCheck= function () {
            var resultSum;

          /* todo loop selectedrows
             resultSum += column(nvlparmvfin); */;

            alert(resultSum);
        };
    </script>

 <ext:GridPanel runat="server" ID="grid1" Height="250px" Frame="true" StoreID="dsGrid1">
                        <ColumnModel runat="server">
                            <Columns>
                                <ext:NumberColumn runat="server" DataIndex="nvlparmvfin" Format=",0.00" Align="Right"/>                             
                            </Columns>
                        </ColumnModel>
                        <SelectionModel>
                            <ext:CheckboxSelectionModel runat="server" Mode="Multi">
                                <Listeners>
                                    <SelectionChange Fn="sumCheck()" />
                                </Listeners> 
                            </ext:CheckboxSelectionModel>
                        </SelectionModel>                       
</ext:GridPanel>
```

If you can help me, thank you very much;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using **[`grid.getSelectionModel()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.selection.Model-method-getSelectionMode)** you will get all selected [`record`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Model).

In this **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2b21)**, I have created a demo using [`grid`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel) in **ExtJS 4.2**. I hope this will help you to solve your problem or achieve your requirement.

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Sum of Selected',
    store: {
        fields: ['product', 'price'],
        data: [{
            product: 'A',
            price: 20
        }, {
            product: 'B',
            price: 52
        }, {
            product: 'C',
            price: 36
        }, {
            product: 'D',
            price: 56
        }]
    },
    columns: [{
        text: 'Product',
        dataIndex: 'product',
        flex: 1
    }, {
        text: 'Price ($)',
        dataIndex: 'price',
        flex: 1
    }],
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    selModel: {
        checkOnly: false,
        mode: 'SIMPLE'
    },
    selType: 'checkboxmodel',
    tbar: ['->', {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        fieldLabel: 'Sum of Selected',
        readOnly: true,
        value: 0
    }],
    buttons: [{
        text: 'Sum of Selected',
        handler: function () {
            var selectionModel = this.up('grid').getSelectionModel();
            if (selectionModel.getCount()) {
                var total = 0;
                Ext.Array.forEach(selectionModel.getSelection(), function (rec) {
                    total += rec.get('price');
                });
                Ext.Msg.alert('Success', 'Total sum of selected product is <br> <b>' + Ext.util.Format.usMoney(total) + '</b>');
            } else {
                Ext.Msg.alert('Info', 'Sorry,No product selected');
            }
        }
    }],

    listeners: {
        selectionchange: function () {
            var grid = this,
                selected = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection(),
                total = 0;
            Ext.Array.forEach(selected, function (rec) {
                total += rec.get('price');
            });
            grid.down('textfield').setValue(total);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to go through the loop of selected record and then store take the value of a perticular column and put it on the count.

your code will similar like this

```
var grd = this.up().up();
var gridSel = grd.getSelection();
var count = 0;
    for(var i=0; i<gridSel.length;i++){
        var num = gridSel[i].data.indexSum;
            num = parseInt(num);
            count += num;
      }
alert(count);
```

I created a fiddle for you. Please check.

[Fiddle](http://You%20have%20to%20go%20through%20the%20loop%20of%20selected%20record%20and%20then%20store%20take%20the%20value%20of%20a%20perticular%20column%20and%20put%20it%20on%20the%20count.%20%20your%20code%20will%20similar%20like%20this%20%20var%20grd%20=%20this.up().up();%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20gridSel%20=%20grd.getSelection();%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20count%20=%200;%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20for(var%20i=0;%20i%3CgridSel.length;i++)%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20num%20=%20gridSel[i].data.indexSum;%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20num%20=%20parseInt(num);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20count%20+=%20num;%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20alert(count);%20I%20created%20a%20fiddle%20for%20you.%20Please%20check.%20%20%20https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2b00)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the example, I'm trying to implement it, but this is giving an error in the browser debug when firing the event, which I'm trying to find.
Uncaught TypeError: s.apply is not a function
at F.fire (ext.axd?v=4.2.0:19)
at F.doFireEvent (ext.axd?v=4.2.0:19)
at F.fireEventArgs (ext.axd?v=4.2.0:19)
at F.fireEvent (ext.axd?v=4.2.0:19)
at F.maybeFireSelectionChange (ext.axd?v=4.2.0:19)
at F.maybeFireSelectionChange (ext.axd?v=4.2.0:19
at F.selectWithEventMulti (ext.axd?v=4.2.0:19
at F.selectWithEvent (ext.axd?v=4.2.0:19)
If necessary I can provide a very simple example code.

Comment: are you using `ExtJS 4` ? Ya it will be good if u provide you complete code. So I can modify as per your code in my local and update you.

Answer (score 0):

Perfect, I made some adjustments and it worked perfectly. The complete sample code follows.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="Ext.Net" Namespace="Ext.Net" TagPrefix="ext" %>
<script runat="server">
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!X.IsAjaxRequest)
        {
            this.Store2.DataSource = new object[]
            {
                new object[] { 'A', 20 },
                new object[] { 'B', 52 },
                new object[] { 'C', 36 }
            };
            this.Store2.DataBind();

        }
    }
</script>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Ext.NET Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <ext:ResourceManager runat="server" />

        <ext:GridPanel runat="server">
            <Store>
                <ext:Store ID="Store2" runat="server">
                    <Model>
                        <ext:Model runat="server" AutoDataBind="true">
                            <Fields>
                                <ext:ModelField Name="product" />
                                <ext:ModelField Name="price" />
                            </Fields>
                        </ext:Model>
                    </Model>

                    <Reader>
                        <ext:ArrayReader />
                    </Reader>
                </ext:Store>
            </Store>
            <ColumnModel runat="server">
                <Columns>
                    <ext:Column runat="server" Header="Product" DataIndex="product" Flex="1" />
                    <ext:Column runat="server" Header="Price ($)" DataIndex="price" Flex="1" />
                </Columns>
            </ColumnModel>
                        <SelectionModel>
                <ext:CheckboxSelectionModel runat="server" Mode="Multi">
                    <Listeners>
                        <SelectionChange Handler="var total = 0;
                                                  var grid = this;
                                                  var selected = grid.getSelection();;
                                                  Ext.Array.forEach(selected, function (rec) {
                                                      total += rec.get('price');
                                                   });
                            alert(total);
                            " />
                    </Listeners>
                </ext:CheckboxSelectionModel>
            </SelectionModel>


        </ext:GridPanel>


    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Many thanks for the reply.